# Gitlab CI runner on my laptop is unable to execute ci because it doesn't have access to the CI_XXX env variables

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have installed and registered gitlab-runner according to the instructions on their documentation. The laptop is running linux mint.

My config.toml looks like this.

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "tim-laptop-docker-runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com"
  token = "REDACTED"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable-dind"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache" , "/home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa:ro"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

if I run the command like this

```
gitlab-runner exec docker build_container
```

I get this error

```
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=9183 revision=8bb608ff version=11.7.0
WARNING: You most probably have uncommitted changes. 
WARNING: These changes will not be tested.         
Running with gitlab-runner 11.7.0 (8bb608ff)
Using Docker executor with image docker:stable ...
Starting service docker:stable-dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:stable-dind ...
Using docker image sha256:5b626cc3459ad077146e8aac1fbe25f7099d71c6765efd6552b9209ca7ea4dc1 for docker:stable-dind ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...

*** WARNING: Service runner--project-0-concurrent-0-docker-0 probably didn't start properly.

Health check error:
ContainerStart: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /runner--project-0-concurrent-0-docker-0 AS /runner--project-0-concurrent-0-docker-0-wait-for-service/service (executor_docker.go:1321:0s)

Service container logs:
2019-02-21T23:09:56.758732636Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)
2019-02-21T23:09:56.758783195Z Could not mount /sys/kernel/security.
2019-02-21T23:09:56.758789589Z AppArmor detection and --privileged mode might break.
2019-02-21T23:09:56.759360791Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)
```

I should not be getting this as I have privileged = true in my config.toml so I run it like this.

```
gitlab-runner exec docker build_container --docker-privileged
```

Now I get this error

```
gitlab-runner exec docker build_container --docker-privileged
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=10088 revision=8bb608ff version=11.7.0
WARNING: You most probably have uncommitted changes. 
WARNING: These changes will not be tested.         
Running with gitlab-runner 11.7.0 (8bb608ff)
Using Docker executor with image docker:stable ...
Starting service docker:stable-dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:stable-dind ...
Using docker image sha256:5b626cc3459ad077146e8aac1fbe25f7099d71c6765efd6552b9209ca7ea4dc1 for docker:stable-dind ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Pulling docker image docker:stable ...
Using docker image sha256:73d492654a095a2f91078b2dfacd0cfe1a1fe25412fac54b4eb2f5a9609ad418 for docker:stable ...
Running on runner--project-0-concurrent-0 via x1...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/project-0'...
done.
Checking out 85297912 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ echo $CI_JOB_TOKEN

$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
FATAL: exit code 1
```

Here I am able to connect to the docker service but when I attempt to log into the docker registry it fails because it has no access to the CI_JOB_TOKEN variable. The echo statement above the login shows that the variable is missing.

How can I get gitlab runner working on my own laptop? Why isn't it obeying the privileged=true in my config file?